# Hibernate: update database tables dynamically according to annotated classes from plugins

Tags: java, hibernate, osgi

We are developing an application that should have support for uploading plugins at run-time. Is it best choice to use osgi framework for this kind of task? 
Could you please explain step-by-step how to enable dynamic creation/update/removal of database tables based on annotated classes in plugin? We are using Hibernate. Thank you very much in advance.

P.S. It should be something like plugins based Atlassian products with Active Objects support.

Comment: At this time, I am not sure this type of question is good for this site. It seems it might be too broad. Also, questions are like to get more answers when they provide a [complete, minimal, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please see the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Well, I'll be happy with at least target words to start with, some links or examples would be much appreciated too

Comment: I do not think you will be able to handle incremental upgrades with Hibernate/JPA well. Check Liquibase. That is the technology that offers the functionality you want.